# email server services for websites

Tags: email, server, api

I have a growing website and I don't want to deal with setting up a mail server to send emails through. Currently I am using Google Apps and sending emails via a Java program that I wrote. However, it seems Google has certain restrictions against that.

Is there a list of email server providers out there. One where we can point our DNS MX record and send emails via an API?

Comment: Are you using the free Google Apps or GA for Business? Because if it's the free one, you have a 500-per-day email quota.

Comment: There is a GA for Business? I am using the free Google Apps one with our domain pointing to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ionFish I went ahead with Amazon SES -- thanks! They have a great system for emails -- within a few days they opened my bandwidth to 10,000 emails per day, more than I need. Awesome service, thanks @ionFish.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the free Google Apps, they impose a 500-email-per-day quota.

Upgrade to Google Apps for Business: http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/ for "unlimited" email. It will save you the trouble of experimenting with new companies and having to migrate MX records.

Comment: It seems Google Apps for Biz has a 2000 outgoing email limit for each user and they do not support bulk emails out via an automated system -- currently they disconnect our connection to the host, I worry the same will occur via the Biz services.

Comment: @somid3 - http://aws.amazon.com/ses/